# TeamCity: revert overriden steps

Tags: teamcity

Situation: we have a set of build configurations based on the same build template. So, all the configs are marked as "based on MySuperTemplate" and all build steps are marked as `(inherited)`. So far so good.
Eventually I introduced a change in a step of a particular build config, not in the template itself. After figuring this out, I applied the change to the template, however corresponding step of that particular build config is still marked as `(inherited, overridden)`.

Question: how to undo that "override state" back to "just inherited" so the step will accept all the changes from the template origin again?

*P.S. TeamCity version is 2021.2.3 (build 99711) if it matters...*

Answer (score 3):

No idea why I didn't notice it before:

- Open the build configuration, go to the grid of steps
- At a grid row with "overridden" step, find "Edit" hotlink accompanied with a small combo-button aside (right-side of the row)
- Open a drop-down for this combo-button and click "Reset" option (it appears for overridden steps only, regular ones are provided with "copy" and "disable" choices)

As simple as that. Now the step is reverted back to the template-defined content.